# How to remove page from pagination URL

Tags: php, pagination

I have written a SEO-friendly pagination function which is working fine. However, my current url looks like this:

**1.** `localhost/test/tastepage.php/test/testpage/page/123`

But what i want to accomplish is:

**2.** `localhost/test/testpage.php/page/123` or `localhost/test/testpage.php/123`

When I go to the url bar and edit my url to like **2** It is working fine. But i want to know, why does my URL look like **1** whenever I load the page for the first time?

Here is what I have in my tastpage.php file:

```
$page=1;//set page number to 1 as default
$sitepath=explode('/',parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],PHP_URL_PATH));//removing slashes from the url and slicing up the url into an array
if(is_array($sitepath)&& !empty($sitepath)){
    if($keys=array_search('page',$sitepath)){;
    print_r($keys);
    $page=(int)$sitepath[$keys+1];
    }
}
function paginate($page,$display,$total){
$sitepath=parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],PHP_URL_PATH);
  if($sitepath!='/'){
      $sitepath=rtrim($sitepath,'/');
      if(stristr($sitepath,'page/')){
          $sitepath=rtrim($sitepath,'0..9');
          $query='';
      }
      else {
         $query=$sitepath .'/page/';
     }
  }
      else {
        $query = 'page/';
    }
$pages=ceil($total/$display );

$first='<a href="'.$sitepath.$query.'1">First</a>';
$last='<a href="'.$sitepath.$query.$pages.'">Last</a>';
$next='<li><a href="'.$sitepath. $query . ($page + 1) . '">»</a></li>';
$preview='<li><a href="'.$sitepath.$query.($page-1).'">«</a></li>';
$numbers="";
for ($i=max(1,$page-5);$i<=min($page+1,$pages);$i++)
{
    if($i==$page){
    $numbers.='<li><a class="active" href="'.$sitepath.$query.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
    }
    else {
        $numbers.='<li><a href="'.$sitepath.$query.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></span></li>';
    }
}
   if($page>1){
     echo $preview;
   }

 echo  $numbers; 

   if($page<$pages){
      echo  $next;
   }
    };

$limit = 10;
//count how many rows 
$total = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pagi")->fetchColumn();

if ($total > 0) {
    $start = $limit * $page - $limit;
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM pagi ORDER BY pg_id LIMIT :start, :limit");
    $sql->bindValue(':start', $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->bindValue(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->execute();
    if ($sql->rowCount() > 0) {
        while ($result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo $result['pg_name'],"<br />";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "no result to fetch";
}
 ?>
```

Comment: why dont you do this logic via htaccess?

Comment: I am a noob when it comes to htaccess.I have configured my apache for htaccess but i really do not know how to do this using htaccess

Answer (score 2):

My answer is an alternative solution for your url problem.
Please put a '.htaccess' file on the root of your website. Place this code on your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/?testpage/(.*) testpage.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Then you can get the current page number by this php code on your testpage.php:

```
<?php
$page = (isset($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1);//holds the current page
echo $page;
?>
```

Try these urls with your browser to test if this solution works:

- http://localhost/test/testpage/1
- http://localhost/test/testpage/10
- http://localhost/test/testpage/100

For an explanation try reading this article: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: I have already tried that solution before but the problem was i had to edit the url bar to see the result but i wanted it to be like when click on the pagination link it should redirect you to that url. Which was not happening in my case

Comment: May be try to declare some constants that you can use for your pagination url. Don't use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] or similar to that because you will have problem with the url, they will concatenate or similir to that... try to set your sitepath.... $sitepath = 'http://localhost/test/testpage/';